# Prolog recursion and stack issue

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to test out recursion in prolog. Based on the KB and conditional statements below, I tried to make a recursive call and wanted to use the one specifically for "eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(X,Z),eastOf(Z,Y)" The query I am using is "eastOf(ave,yonge)" which should use that recursive call and state that X is ave, Y is yonge and Z is collegePark. However the proglog program i am using current (ECliPSe) iss giving me this error "*** Overflow of the local/control stack!
You can use the "-l kBytes" (LOCALSIZE) option to have a larger stack.
Peak sizes were: local stack 11024 kbytes, control stack 120048 kbytes"

Find below my .pl file

```
eastOf(collegePark,yonge).
eastOf(sushi,eaton).
eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(Y,X). 
eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(X,Z), eastOf(Z,Y).

westOf(ellington,yonge). 
westOf(ryerson,sushi).
westOf(ave,collegePark).
westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf(Y,X).
westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf(X,Z), westOf(Z,Y).
```

Comment: The predicate `eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(X,Z), eastOf(Z,Y).` isn't a good rule. It says that *`X` is east of `Y` if `X` is west of `Z` and `Z` is east of `Y`*. That's not necessarily true.

Comment: Could you provide an example for when this isn't true?

Comment: Sure: Denver, CO is west of New York, NY, and New York, NY, is east of Chicago, IL, but Denver, CO, is NOT east of Chicago, IL.

Comment: So from that predicate it is actually finding that X is north of Y not actually east? Is that correct?

Comment: No, that's not even conclusive. You can't deduce north or south from an east or west relationship, unless you're referring to an unusual, non-spherical geometry. If you are just talking about east and west, and you ignore the fact that A can be either east of B or west of B depending upon which way around the globe you go, then you can say that if A is east of B, and B is east of C, then A is east of C.

Comment: Oh then would this suffice eastOf(A,B) :- eastOf(B,C), eastOf(A,C) as a recursive function to find out whether A is east of B?

Comment: No, you'd want, `eastOf(A, B) :- eastOf(C, B), eastOf(A, C).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(Y,X).

westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf(Y,X).
```

The infinite loop has occurred in the combination of these two predicates. 
Even if stack size is large, size over occurs.
I change your program as follows.

```
eastOf_data(collegePark,yonge).
eastOf_data(sushi,eaton).
eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf_data(Y,X). 
eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf_data(X,Z), eastOf_data(Z,Y).

westOf_data(ellington,yonge). 
westOf_data(ryerson,sushi).
westOf_data(ave,collegePark).
westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf_data(Y,X).
westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf_data(X,Z), westOf_data(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `eastOf(yonge,collegePark)` as your first statement. Right now it never finds an atomic statement starting with either 'ave' or 'yonge', and keeps looping between `eastOf(X,Y) :- westOf(Y,X)` and `westOf(X,Y) :- eastOf(Y,X)`.